# How to use .setError

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

I use .setError function. But it checks the text field only when the save button is clicked, go to SecondActivity and press Back button on device to see it can't be left empty!

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_card);

save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.save);
save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override   
public void onClick(View v) {

EditText Name2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtName);
if( Name2.getText().toString().length() == 0 )
Name2.setError( "First name is required!" );

Intent intent = new Intent(NewCard.this, Template.class);
startActivity(intent);

}
});
```

Any idea on how i can check when button is clicked but not proceeding to SecondActivity if Name2 is blank? And beside length(), i also want to check for numbers, undesired characters etc. if possible. Thanks for assistance.

Comment: Show us where you call `startActivity()`

Comment: @Tanis.7x i edit the code. You can check. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to create an `else` for your `if`, then move your call to `startActivity()` into that like so:

```
// Expand this condiditional to perform whatever other validation you want
if( Name2.getText().toString().length() == 0 ) {
    Name2.setError( "First name is required!" );
} else {
    // Validation passed, show next Activity
    Intent intent = new Intent(NewCard.this, Template.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Thank. this works for me. If you don't mind can you help me also how i can check the text/content as if user shouldn't use undesired character but he did!

Comment: I would check out the [Java String documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). The String class contains a number of methods that will help you here such as `contains()`.